# Search optimization with pandas multi-index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, search, optimization, multi-index

I want to know if there is a way to optimize a search that I am doing. I have a multi-index (3 levels) dataframe `df`, like this:

```
IndexID IndexDateTime IndexAttribute ColumnA ColumnB
   1      2015-02-05        8           A       B
   1      2015-02-05        7           C       D
   1      2015-02-10        7           X       Y
```

My problem is that I want to know if a given date, lets say for example `2015-02-10` has data in `ColumnA`, with the same `IndexID` and `IndexAttribute`, a given day before (5 in this case), and if it has, get it and add it to a new column, like this:

```
IndexID IndexDateTime IndexAttribute ColumnA ColumnB NewColumn
   1      2015-02-05        8           A       B       -1
   1      2015-02-05        7           C       D       -1
   1      2015-02-10        7           X       Y        C
```

I want to perform this search on every row in my dataframe, which has 19million rows. The way I am doing this is:

```
df['NewColumn'] = df.apply(lambda r: get_data(df, r.IndexID, r.IndexDateTime , r.IndexAttribute , 5), axis=1)
```

Where `get_data` is:

```
def get_data(df, IndexID, IndexDateTime , IndexAttribute , days_before):
    idx = pd.IndexSlice
    date = (IndexID - pd.to_timedelta(days_before, 'd'))
    try:
        res = df.loc[idx[IndexID, date, IndexAttribute ],'ColumnA']
        return res
    except KeyError:
        return -1
```

This is extremely slow, taking over 2 hours. I was wondering if it could be a faster way.
Problems:

- The date to search may exist, may not.
- For each `IndexDateTame`I can not know how many IndexAttributes are.
  They are ints thought, and they are in a descending order.

I cant do a shift because I don't know how many data are in the middle of two rows. Some ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy can be pretty fast. You just need to iterate through the columns in the dataframe as numpy array. Hope it helps:

```
%time
def myfunc(df, days_before=5):

     # Fill A column witH -1s
     result = -np.ones_like(df.values[:, -1:])

     # Slice the first 3 columns and shift the dates 
     # to get the index that we are looking for
     idx = np.array((df['IndexID'].values,
                     df['IndexDateTime'] - pd.to_timedelta(days_before, 'd'),
                     df['IndexAttribute'].values)).T

     # Look for days matching in the first 3 columns
     _idx_comp = df.values[:, :3][np.newaxis, :] == np.array(idx)[:, np.newaxis]

     # Get the index where there is a match
     # between the row of the dataframe and the desired searched rows
     idx_found = np.where(np.all(_idx_comp, axis=-1))

     # Assign the corresponding rows to its required value
     result[idx_found[0]] = df['ColumnA'].values[idx_found[-1]]

     return result

df.assign(NewColumn=myfunc(df))

CPU times: user 2 µs, sys: 1e+03 ns, total: 3 µs
Wall time: 5.96 µs

   IndexID IndexDateTime  IndexAttribute ColumnA ColumnB NewColumn
0        1    2015-02-05               8       A       B        -1
1        1    2015-02-05               7       C       D        -1
2        1    2015-02-10               7       X       Y         C
```

Comment: I will test it when I have time and I will post results. Thank you, bona nit!

Comment: It works wonderfully, except I got an error in `result[idx_found[0]] = df['ColumnA'].values[idx_found[-1]]`, since you are trying to assing a row shape(X,) in a column shape(X,1). I have a reshape to the row, but it's a great way to do the search. Testing times now.

Comment: It's strange, I don't get any errors. I'm using the same dataframe, no multiindex, and dates converted to datetime `df['IndexDateTime'] = df['IndexDateTime'].apply(pd.to_datetime)`. Maybe it's something to do with versions

Comment: I'm using pandas: `0.23.4` and numpy: `1.15.3` and python: `3.6.2`.

Comment: Pandas `0.23.4`, Numpy `1.15.2`, Python `3.6.0`. It is strange but whatever, just to let you know this takes about 10 minutes, wonderful improvement!

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is O(m.n) solution, however should faster than you original one

```
l = []
for _, y in df.groupby(level=[0, 2], sort=False):
    s = y.index.get_level_values(level=1).values
    l.append(((s - s[:, None]) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D') == -5).dot(y.ColumnA.values))

df['NewCOL'] = np.concatenate(l)
df

Out[48]: 
                                     ColumnA ColumnB NewCOL
IndexID IndexDateTime IndexAttribute                       
1       2015-02-05    8                    A       B       
                      7                    C       D       
        2015-02-10    7                    X       Y      C
```

Comment: I kinda understand what you do there but the append line confuses me. Could you explain it a bit?

Comment: @Soutuyo Append it to store the result for the for loop, thta is so call numpy broadcast

Comment: Will check it carefully later and answer times, but that division `np.timedelta64(1, 'D') == -5` loses me a bit.

Comment: Ok, so if I am not wrong, you are checking every date in groupby `IndexID` and `IndexAttribute`. If exists a differente of 5 days, you do a multiplication to get only that true values, right?

Comment: I was testing this code, and if there are more `IndexDateTime` than `IndexAttribute`, in some cases the data returned is wrong. Every `IndexDateTime` can have from 1 to x `IndexAttributes`, so you can not append `s` like that.